# Qt 5.9.5 in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Error "GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged"

Tags: qt, gtk, qt5, ubuntu-18.04

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and have just installed and am trying to run Qt but whenever I open a dialog box within Qt, such as when I want to Open an existing Project or File, it causes Qt Creator to freeze until I terminate it. Creating a new Project or File does not cause this to happen (different kind of window I imagine).

The version I have is Qt Creator 4.5.2 based on Qt 5.9.5.

I tried running `qtcreator` from the command line and when I go to open a file or folder from within the GUI the command line returns the following (and the GUI freezes):

```
    $ qtcreator
    Gtk-Message: 01:33:28.712: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged
```

Note, the Gtk-Message only occurs when I do something in Qt that would bring up a dialog box such as to navigate to and select a file. The Qt GIU freezes at this point.

I hope someone knows how to fix this or if it's a compatibility issues between Ubuntu 18.04 and the versions of Qt Creator and Qt that I am using.

Comment: UPDATE: It turns out that Qt isn't freezing, but that the dialog box was opening up somewhere off of my display (making the rest of the GUI an inactive display). I fixed that part with some changes to display settings but I'm still curious about the error I see in the terminal (the Gtk-Message.)

Comment: I see the same error message when calling QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self) from PySide2 (where self is instance of QMainWindow).

Comment: News? I'm facing a very similar error but I'm not able to catch the exception that generates the Gtk-Message. When I open a dialog box (eg. to select a file) I only see the window frame and its borders: the dialog content is not drawn. However, if I click inside the "transparent" dialog I'm actually able to interact with its buttons, etc.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58122168/6660373?